# API Gateway (Azure, AWS) traffic routing based on JWT issuer claim

Tags: routes, aws-api-gateway, azure-api-management, api-gateway, network-traffic

I have a question about routing traffic within an API gateway using policies.

I wish to call different backend servers based on a claim (issuer) in the user's JWT (JSON Web Token) from the same API gateway endpoint.

Specifically, can I write a policy to do JWT claim based routing just like I can use HTTP Headers in the policy, or will I have to call a lambda or azure function and then call the backend services by inspecting the token in the lambda ?

We are trying to centralize the access to the APIs on our multiple server instances and our use case is given below. Can you please advice :-

- 1.a - **UserA** gets Access Token from **ServerA** Auth Services
- 2 - **UserA** calls the **API Gateway**
- 3 - **UserA** is routed to **ServerA WebAPI** based on his Token's issuer claim (ServerA)
- 1.b. - **UserB** gets Access Token from **ServerB** Auth Services
- 2 - **UserB** calls the **API Gateway**
- 3 - **UserB** is routed to **ServerB WebAPI** based on his Token's issuer claim (ServerB)

[image]

Please advice.

Comment: In my opinion, I have two api: companyA.net/getUserInfo, companyB.net/getUserInfo. Then I need to create a application to play the role of gateway in your picture. This app need to analyze JWT token and decide to call which api(e.g. get keywords 'companyA' from token). I know a little about azure api management and I didn't find any configuration about api gateway.

Comment: so in other words, i'll need to pass the request through a lambda or azure function, right ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's ok, request through an app to handle it and redirect to the correct server. The app play the role of transfer station.

Comment: did you find a way?